# Работа с матрицами

Tags: delphi, pascal

Как найти определитель матрицы? Как найти обратную матрицу?

Нужны функции на Pascal / Delphi.

Насколько корректно работает вот эта функция?

```
Const
maxCount=300;
type
  TArrayReal=array[0..maxCount, 0..maxCount] of real;

var
   Count:integer;

procedure GetBackMatrix(source:TArrayReal;var Back:TArrayReal);
var k, i, j: integer;
begin
 for i:=0 to Count - 1 do
 for j:=0 to Count - 1 do Back[i,j]:=source[i,j];

 for k:=0 to Count - 1 do
 begin
      for i:=0 to Count - 1 do
       for j:=0 to Count - 1 do
       begin
            if (i=k) and (j=k) then
               source[i,j] := 1/Back[i,j];
               if (i=k) and (j<>k) then
                  source[i,j] := -Back[i,j]/Back[k,k];
               if (i<>k) and (j=k) then
                  source[i,j] := Back[i,k]/Back[k,k];

               if (i<>k) and (j<>k) then
                  source[i,j] := Back[i,j] - Back[k,j] * Back[i,k]/Back[k,k];
       end;
      for i:= 0 to Count - 1 do
       for j:= 0 to Count - 1 do Back[i, j]:= source[i, j];
 end;
end;
```

Comment: кнопка 101010 помогает отформатировать код

Comment: А где взять пример?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Явная работа за автора. Так что код писать не буду, тем более, что там нет ничего сложного.
2. Смотрим [тут](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%EF%F0%E5%E4%E5%EB%E8%F2%E5%EB%FC), что такое детерминант, а [тут](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%E1%F0%E0%F2%ED%E0%FF_%EC%E0%F2%F0%E8%F6%E0) - что такое обратная матрица. Видим там формулы. Делаем у себя в программе двумерный массив, представляем, что это матрица, и интерпретируем формулы из вышеуказанных ссылок в вашей матрице.